# "/1/2/3/".split("/")

Tags: python, string

It's too hot & I'm probably being retarded.

```
>>> "/1/2/3/".split("/")
['', '1', '2', '3','']
```

Whats with the empty elements at the start and end?

Edit: Thanks all, im putting this down to heat induced brain failure. The docs aren't quite the clearest though, from http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

```
"Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string"
```

Is there a word before the first, or after the last "/"?

Comment: It's because you have a / before the 1 and after the 3

Comment: Variation to remove empty strings (this removes them from the middle as well if you happen to have `//` in your string): `[x for x in '/1/2/3/'.split('/') if x <> '']`

Comment: @Brian Neat! Should post that as an answer.

Comment: @ceejayoz: post solution that uses `if x <> ''`? please no.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compare with:

```
"1/2/3".split("/")
```

Empty elements are still elements.

You could use `strip('/')` to trim the delimiter from the beginning/end of your string.

Comment: Summarizing: `"/1/2/3/".strip("/").split("/")`. Easiest way to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

As JLWarlow says, you have an extra '/' in the string. Here's another example:

```
>>> "//2//3".split('/')
['', '', '2', '', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Slashes are *separators*, so there are empty elements before the first and after the last.

Comment: Just adding: that's to say, each separator has something before and something after, including the first and last separators

Answer (score 1):

you're splitting on `/`. You have 4 `/`, so, the list returned will have 5 elements.

Comment: Except they're forward slashes!

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what I would expect, but we are all different :)

What would you expect from: : "1,,2,3".split(",") ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip()` to get rid of the leading and trailing fields... Then call `split()` as before.

Comment: Except in python it is `strip()`, not `trim()` :)

Comment: Damn it, I even knew that. How I mistyped that I'll never know. Fixing shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in "//1///2/3///".split("/") if x != ""]
```

Comment: err, now I see Brian posted almost exactly the same solution on the comments before..

Comment: you could just check with `if x`