# Python: first character when splitting

Tags: python, string, split

I just noticed the `split` method produces an empty string in the result list if the first character is a delimiter string.

Example:

```
>>> s = '/foo/bar/blarg'
>>> s.split('/')
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'blarg']
```

I expected this to produce:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'blarg']
```

Is there some reason why this is desirable behavior, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: i dont see any problem with this behavior.  empty sting is still a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["/1/2/3/".split("/")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142428/1-2-3-split)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the desired behaviour, because otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish between `"/foo".split("/")` and `"foo".split("/')`.

When I'm using split and know that I don't want possibly empty strings, I'll use `filter(None, foo.split("/"))` to remove them:

```
>>> filter(None, "/foo//bar".split("/"))
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to David's answer... split seperates sections of a string by a given delimiter.  an empty string must be considered a valid section, otherwise, splitting cases like this would also be problematic:

```
'//'.split('/')
```

What else should this return, other than `['', '', '']`?

Answer (score 2):

Contrast these examples:

```
>>> s = '/foo/bar/blarg'
>>> s.split('/')
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'blarg']
```

vs

```
>>> s = 'foo/bar/blarg'
>>> s.split('/')
['foo', 'bar', 'blarg']
```

having an extra `''` in your list means you can distinguish between whether there was a `/` at the start or your string or not

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, one way to prevent empty strings at the beginning and end of your list is to strip off leading and trailing `/` characters:

```
>>> s = '/foo/bar/blarg'
>>> s.strip('/').split('/')
['foo', 'bar', 'blarg']
```

Note that you would still get an empty string if there were consecutive `/` characters in the middle of the string.